# How do I specify a custom class on a formtastic 1.2.4 field?

Tags: formtastic

I have this custom form builder, and it calls:

```
basic_input_helper(:text_field, :date, :date_value, options.merge!({:html_options => {:class => "datepicker"}})) if options[:response_class] == "date"
```

The fourth parameter there are the options (the `html` options, if I read the code correctly), and I would expect that line to add `class="datepicker"` to my input field, but instead I get:

```
<input id="r_3_date_value" name="r[3][date_value]" size="30" type="text" value="2012-07-02" />
```

No `class` attribute at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the key `:input_html` instead of `:html_options`

```
basic_input_helper(:text_field, :date, :date_value, options.merge!({:input_html => {:class => "datepicker"}})) if options[:response_class] == "date"
```

The code gets evaluated [like this (source on github)](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/1.2.4/lib/formtastic.rb#L646), you can see the evaluation for input html on line 647

Comment: Got around to actually implementing this today. Thank you for the correction. Totally fixed my problem, and was absolutely worth the 200 rep.

Comment: You're welcome, Really glad to hear that! I think your question went a bit lost there because it had only the formtastic tag, actually don't know anymore how i found it myself. Appreciate the additional rep and once again, nice to hear it helped, thanks!